# User is undefined when changing discord bot presence

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Im trying to change my bot's presence using the following code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = {
    name: 'setstatus', //command name
    description: "Sets the bot's presence", //command description
    args: true, //needs arguments? delete line if no
    usage: `<online|invisible|dnd|idle>`, //usage instructions w/o command name and prefix
    cooldown: 5, //cooldown in seconds, defaults to 3
    ownerOnly: true, //need to be the owner? delete line if no
    aliases: [],
    execute(message, args, prefix, user) { //inside here command stuff
        if (args[0] === 'online') {
            client.user.setPresence({ status: 'online' })
            message.channel.send(`Status set to ${args[0]}`)
        } else if (args[0] === 'idle') {
            client.user.setPresence({ status: 'idle' })
            message.channel.send(`Status set to ${args[0]}`)
        } else if (args[0] === 'invisible') {
            client.user.setPresence({ status: 'invisible' })
            message.channel.send(`Status set to ${args[0]}`)
        } else if (args[0] === 'dnd') {
            client.user.setPresence({ status: 'dnd' })
            message.channel.send(`Status set to ${args[0]}`)
        } else {
            message.channel.send(`Invalid argument: ${args[0]}. Valid arguments are:\nonline, idle, invisible, dnd`)
        }
    },
};
```

But when executing this, I get the error 'user is not defined.' Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should use the client from your main file. Use `<message>.client` to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to redo initial client at each commands since it already attach to your message and you can get it easily with `message.client.user`

So this line `const client = new Discord.Client();` is useless since your bot is initial but it even not login to get the details yet

Comment: Ok, but now the bot status wont change, yet the command succeeds.
Edit: nevermind, it just took a minute to update.